Show duplicated lines
After doing :sort u I need to see what were the duplicated lines.
This is what I'm currently doing:
:w temp.txt | :sort u | :vsplit temp.txt | :sort | :windo diffthis

This creates a temp file to compare with.
My question is: Is there a builtin or at least a more elegant way to do this? I would love to see other options.

What about :command! ShowDuplicateLines <commands you wrote above>?

Building upon @filbranden's answer, here is a variant that:

performs :sort and then :sort u in two scratch windows to keep the original buffer untouched,
doesn't mess with registers.

function! CreateScratchWindow(filename, suffix, filetype)
    leftabove vnew
    setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=delete noswapfile
    silent execute 'file ' .. a:filename .. ' ' .. a:suffix
    let &filetype = a:filetype
endfunction

function! ShowDupes()
    let fname = bufname()
    let ftype = &filetype
    let original = getline(1,'$')
    call CreateScratchWindow(fname, '[:sort]', ftype)
    call setline(1, original)
    sort
    let sorted = getline(1,'$')
    call CreateScratchWindow(fname, '[:sort u]', ftype)
    call setline(1, sorted)
    sort u
    .,+1windo diffthis
endfunction

command! ShowDupes call ShowDupes()

BONUS, here is an evolution of the command above, that:

allows the diff of one or more arbitrary commands outputs,
can be used with external commands:

function! ShowDiffOf(...)
    let fname = bufname()
    let ftype = &filetype
    if a:000->len() == 1
        diffthis
    endif
    for cmd in a:000
        let linesToCopyOver = getline(1,'$')
        leftabove vnew
        setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=delete noswapfile
        silent execute 'file ' .. fname .. ' [' .. fnameescape(cmd) .. ']'
        let &filetype = ftype
        call setline(1, linesToCopyOver)
        call execute(cmd)
        diffthis
    endfor
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ ShowDiffOf call ShowDiffOf(<f-args>)

Basically, you provide the arbitrary commands you want to perform as arguments to :ShowDiffOf, which passes them as a list to ShowDiffOf(), which loops over the list and creates a diffed scratch window for each command.
Which kind of starts to look a lot like a cross between this gist of mine and the :help :DiffOrig command demonstrated in the documentation.
Here are a couple of examples:

:ShowDiffOf :sort :sort\ u


:ShowDiffOf %!tac



Possible improvements include:

add the ability to decide the direction and orientation of the new windows,
ensure the order of windows and the order of commands are coherent,
find a catchier name,
decide if commands must be chained or executed on the original text.


Looks amazing! Thanks for building upon that!

You can implement this using a scratch buffer (see :help special-buffers) that's not backed by a file with the contents that you want to make temporary.
You can put this all together into a function, that will copy the contents of the current buffer, then create a window with a temporary buffer, put the contents there, then finally remove the duplicates in your original buffer and set up a diff between the two buffers.
Putting it all together:
function! ShowDupes()
    let fname = bufname()
    let ftype = &filetype
    let savereg = getreginfo('z')
    sort
    silent %yank z
    leftabove vnew
    setlocal buftype=nofile
    setlocal bufhidden=delete
    setlocal noswapfile
    silent execute 'file' fname..'[dupes]'
    let &filetype = ftype
    silent put z
    1delete
    call setreg('z', savereg)
    diffthis
    wincmd p
    sort u
    diffthis
endfunction

command! ShowDupes call ShowDupes()

Then calling :ShowDupes from any window will set up the diff the way you want it to, and closing the window with the [dupes] buffer will just make it go away.

Instead of clobbering quote-z , you could :read #? Minor nit, though

Updated to save and restore quote-z across the call. Also prefer to yank and put the contents rather than re-read the file, in case the contents were already modified in the first place. As is, this even works on a new file or anonymous buffer. Thanks!

:help getline() and :help setline() allow you to bypass registers (and all the yanking/putting/saving/restoring) entirely and a few other commands. Also there are some characters missing on the second savereg line.

Thanks both! I forgot read targeted the file and not the buffer :/
